# Need help setting y range for matplotlib for scientific data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple text file with scientific data, with one data item on each line.
I want to plot it simply as sequential items as y-axis.
I call this:  list_y

Within the Python script I create a list that is a simple sequential number list for the x-axis.
I call this:  list_x

When I plot, using the matplotlib calls, the same as dozens of examples that I have read, I get unexpected results.
Matplotlab does not seem to give a y-axis from the smallest-to-largest of my y value data items.
It seems to plot number pairs - not what I would call a "graph".

I have read various examples and watched Youtube demonstrations with the exact code that I am using, and those examples all give a result that I would expect.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 10 12:18:57 2020

@author: usera
"""

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# data in data01a.txt is:  0.1  0.22  0.33  0.5  0.6  0.66  1  .9  

data_han = open('data01a.txt', 'r')
list_y = data_han.readlines()
data_han.close()

y_size = len(list_y)

ii = 0
list_x = []

#follow while stmt creates a numeric list for x-axis
while ii < y_size:
    list_x.append(ii)
    ii += 1

plt.xlabel('Sequence')
plt.ylabel('Value')

plt.legend()

plt.grid('True')

#following 3 lines of code commented out 
#since it causes strange results
#axes = plt.gca()
#axes.set_xlim(0,10)
#axes.set_ylim(0,1)

#following commented out code does not give correct x axis
#and no line is plotted at all
#plt.axis(0,10,0,1)

#following commented out code does not give correct y axis
#plt.xlim(0,10)
#plt.ylim(0,1)

plt.plot(list_x, list_y, label='Test Plot')

plt.savefig('test01a.png')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot produced by matplotlib]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your data is string and is being sorted as a string. Cast it to float and see if that works for you

Comment: Like so `list_y = [float(value_string) for value_string in data_han.readlines()]`.

Comment: Also you can use simply `list_x = list(range(len(y_list)))`.

Comment: To better characterize your dataset include print statements for each axis and test their type.

Comment: I would recommend using a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very "quick and dirty" approach would be something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y_data = [0.1, 0.22, 0.33, 0.5, 0.6, 0.66, 1, 0.9]
y_data = sorted(y_data)

x_data = [i+1 for i in range(len(y_data))]

plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
plt.show()
```

I stripped off, every part not needed for a very basic example. So, feel free to add any configuration for grid, title or labels later.

I assumed, you are able to read and parse the data from your input file into a list of floats called `y_data`. In addition, I assumed that you want to sort the y-values from lowest to highest, as you have stated:

> does not seem to give a y-axis from the smallest-to-largest of my y value data items

If you want to keep the original order of your `y_data`, simply remove the line `y_data = sorted(y_data)`.

Next thing we should elaborate on, is plotting with `plt.plot()`. According to [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), providing x-values is optional and we are allowed to provide y-values without any x-values. When doing so, the element index of the corresponding y-value will be used as the x-value. This would result in a value range of 0...N-1. You might want to have 1...N which we can achieve by calculating a very basic list of x-values based on the length list containing the y-values `y_data`. By doing so, we can pass both lists `x_data` and `y_data` to `plt.plot()` and get the desired output:

[image: Plot with explicitly given x-values]

The output without explicitly given x-values would be quite similar, but 0-based instead of 1-based on the x-axis. Change `plt.plot(x_data, y_data)` into `plt.plot(y_data)` to see the difference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ALL. Got it working. I should have pulled the :StackExchange Rip Cord" sooner, but I really try to find an answer that is already posted. Thank you again.